# How do I submit a new update to an existing app from a project I started from scratch?

Tags: xcode, submit

Well, I submitted an app to the app store, but my little cousin went on my computer and screwed up the project so badly that I had to start from scratch. So I rebuilt everything back to how it was, and I am trying to submit it to the app store and it obviously isn't recognizing it as the same app,

> (Please make sure that you have set up a record for this application
>   on iTunes Connect.)

although the bundle ID is the same as the old one. How can I go about doing this? I have to get this update out fast, any replies are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Have you prepared the app in iTunesconnect to receive an update?
After you have chosen to "Add version", you still have to press the button "Ready to upload binary" in the top right corner of the details screen of the app.
It *should* be sufficient to keep the app bundle the same in order to update. 
You also have to use the same provisioning profiles as you used before.